# Múltiple viewBox en SVG

Tags: svg, illustrator

Tengo un problema al crear un SVG al vuelo, añadiéndole múltiples etiquetas SVG con `viewBox` distinto, al momento de exportar se ve perfecto en el navegador, pero al abrirlo con Illustrator no lo muestra de manera correcta.

Mi código:

```html
<svg class="addmask" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="enable-background:new -40 -40 120 120;" xml:space="preserve">
  <svg class="addon_content" viewBox="0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve" style="enable-background:new -40 -40 120 120;">
    <g>
      <defs>
        <path id="55_test_button_mask" d="M62,62H-1V-1h63V62z M30.5,21c-5.246,0-9.5,4.254-9.5,9.5s4.254,9.5,9.5,9.5s9.5-4.254,9.5-9.5
                                          S35.746,21,30.5,21z"/>
      </defs>
      <clipPath id="55_test_button_mask_1_">
        <use xlink:href="#55_test_button_mask"  overflow="visible"/>
      </clipPath>
    </g>
    <path id="55_test_button_addon" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M30.5,22c-4.69,0-8.5,3.81-8.5,8.5s3.81,8.5,8.5,8.5s8.5-3.81,8.5-8.5S35.19,22,30.5,22 M29,27.5c0,0.828-0.672,1.5-1.5,1.5
                                                                               S26,28.328,26,27.5s0.672-1.5,1.5-1.5S29,26.672,29,27.5z M35,27.5c0,0.828-0.672,1.5-1.5,1.5S32,28.328,32,27.5s0.672-1.5,1.5-1.5
                                                                               S35,26.672,35,27.5z M29,33.5c0,0.828-0.672,1.5-1.5,1.5S26,34.328,26,33.5s0.672-1.5,1.5-1.5S29,32.672,29,33.5z M35,33.5
                                                                               c0,0.828-0.672,1.5-1.5,1.5S32,34.328,32,33.5s0.672-1.5,1.5-1.5S35,32.672,35,33.5z"/>
  </svg>
  <g clip-path="url(#55_test_button_mask_1_)">
    <svg x="-40" y="-40" width="120px" height="120px" data-box="-40 -40 120 120" viewBox="-40 -40 120 120" class="addon_mask_plhld">
      <g id="55_test_button_icon_placeholder" class="icnplhld">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="id_svgCanvas" x="0px" y="0px" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
          <g id="55152510_Shape_5_xA0_Clipping_Path_1_">
            <g>
              <path d="M20,2C10.059,2,2,10.059,2,20s8.059,18,18,18c9.941,0,18-8.059,18-18S29.941,2,20,2z M31,23h-8v8h-6v-8H9v-6h8V9h6v8h8V23z"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: ¿Entonces el problema es que Illustrator no sabe cómo importar múltiples SVG correctamente?

Comment: Muchos problemas que tuve al crear mi web se resolvieron primero creando un dibujo en el programa _Adobe Illustrator_ (un software de gráficos vectoriales) y ver cómo tenía éste la forma de exportación, para así poder crear el [_SVG_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) al vuelo. Así a bote pronto veo muchos _SVG_ dentro de un mismo **.svg**. Aunque eso es correcto, puedes eliminarlos.